How to perform Zernike fit on a surface?
I have been wanting to perform Zernike fit on a distorted beam at the pupil plane which has a grid size of -D to D.
The expression to relate the surface wavefront and zernike polynomials is given as:
W(r,$\theta$) = $\sum c_{n} Z(r, \theta)$
Zernike polynomials are orthogonal on a unit disk. But my wavefront surface is in a different grid.
What I have understood is that the coordinate system should be same for Zernike polynomials and the wavefront to calculate correct coefficients. But how to do it? If my i use a normalized grid for zernike polynomials,
$W(\rho R) = \sum c_{n} Z(\rho R)$
where $\rho = r/R$ and R is the radius of the circle while $\rho$ is the normalized coordinate.
From the paper, https://opg.optica.org/josaa/fulltext.cfm?uri=josaa-20-2-209&id=71137, I understood that the coefficients could be converted. But I don't know if this is necessary for my case.
If this transformation is to be used on Zernike coefficients, here is how I performed it,
I have a coordinate grid of size [-D,D], r = D and Z = [-1,1] with N pixels for both cases.
I perform a Zernike fit and get coefficients. Now i put into the code implemented in the paper, where cn is the coefficients I calculated, and aperture is D. So, this should give me new coefficients? But I am getting wrong value, so i assume I am understanding somewhere wrong. Could anyone help me with understanding the theory behind it?
